# How can I resolve this problem of eloquant display data?

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, controller

I want to do this request with laravel ( i have 3 tables users , userprojet and projets ) users hasmany projets and projet hasmany users that's why i do another table userprojet to join the two table and now i try to extract the projet of a specific user with this request
in model projei do this method:

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projet');
}
```

//model user

```
 public function projets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Projet::class, 'user_projet');
}

//in the controller projet i do this method 

public function getProjectsUserConnecte(){
    $user = User::with('projets')->first();
    return $user->projets;
}
```

but any thing dosen't display and i have no error 
please someone know the problem ?

Comment: Maybe you misspelled 'user_projet'. Should it be 'user_project'

Comment: no the name is 'user_projet' i'm sure about the name

Comment: plz post the migration about this three tables.

Comment: //projets table
  */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('durre')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('owner')->nullable();

        });
    }

Comment: **  */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('durre')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('owner')->nullable();

        });
    }**

Comment: user table :
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: //user_projet table:

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('projet_id');
        $table->foreign('projet_id')->references('id')->on('projets')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('membre')->nullbale();